# Scrabble game increases score of second player by 1 inconsistently

Tags: c, cs50

Example:

player 1 enters "all"

player 2 enters "do"

Expected Result: Tie!

Actual Result: Player 2 Wins! (do ends up valuing at 4 points

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Points assigned to each letter of the alphabet
int POINTS[] = {1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 8, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 8, 4, 10};

int compute_score(string word);

int main(void)
{

    // Get input words from both players

    string word1 = get_string("Player 1: ");

    string word2 = get_string("Player 2: ");

    // Score both words

    int score1 = compute_score(word1);

    int score2 = compute_score(word2);

    // TODO: Print the winner

    if (score1 > score2)

    {

        printf("Player 1 wins!");

    }

    else if (score1 == score2)

    {

        printf("It's a tie!");

    }
    else
    {
        printf("Player 2 wins!");
    }
}

int compute_score(string word)
{

    // TODO: Compute and return score for string

    // set initial score to 0

    int score = 0;

    int letter = 0;

    char lower_word[strlen(word)];

    // lowercasing the letters in word

    for (int j = 0; j < strlen(word); j++)

    {

        lower_word[j]= tolower(word[j]);

    }

    // cycle through the string

    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(lower_word); i < n; i++)

    {

        // check to see if character is within scorable range

        if (lower_word[i] >= 'a' && lower_word[i] <= 'z')

        {

            // make the value be within the list of points

            letter = lower_word[i] - 97;

            // grab score and add it to current score

            score = score + POINTS[letter];

        }

        // if score isn't a value within the range

        else

        {

            // add nothing to the current score

            score = score + 0;

        }

    }

    // returns final score value

    return score;

}
```

Comment: Sorry about the poor formatting, new to this

Comment: `strlen(lower_word)` causes undefined behaviour. The `strlen` function only works on strings. Strings are always terminated by a null terminator, but you did not place one for `lower_word` .

Answer (score 1):

It seems the following piece in compute_score leads to error:

```
char lower_word[strlen(word)];
```

Assuming strlen(word) is 5, then lower_word has 5 char space (5 bytes). BUT, in C, a char string needs 1 more byte to contain the ending '\0'; so actually lower_word needs 6 bytes to contain a char string.

In your code, lower_word has no (guarantted) ending '\0', so the strlen(lower_word) in the follong loop may work for unknown times...

```
for (int i = 0, n = strlen(lower_word); i < n; i++)
```

What modification I suggest is:

```
char lower_word[strlen(word) + 1] = {0};
```

Comment: Or, simply compute the number of characters once `int len = strlen( word );`, and use `len` in both of the `for()` loops...